# Reveal: jQuery Modal Plugin Won't Appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use [Reveal by Zurb](http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) to display a form, yet when I select the item that triggers the event the screen darkens like Reveal is working, but it will not show the pane. Any ideas? Thanks a lot for the help!

Planner.js

```
$(function() {

    $('.event_list li').click( function(e) {
        console.log(this.id);
        $('#update_view_content').reveal('http://example.com/user/planner/update/'+this.id);
    });

    $('#updateForm').live('submit', function() {
        var data = $('#updateForm').serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        $.post(url, data);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the documentation online it seems there are no parameters for the `reveal()` method - the reveal method just shows a div on the screen, so

You would created markup on your page :

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
     <h1>Modal Title</h1>
     <p>Any content could go in here.</p>
     <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

then reveal it ...

```
 $('#myButton').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#myModal').reveal();
 });
```

If you want to load something into the div and then reveal i suggest this approach :

```
$('.event_list li').click( function(e) {
    console.log(this.id);
    $('#update_view_content').load('http://example.com/user/planner/update/'+this.id,function() {
        $('#update_view_content').reveal();
    });
});
```

That should load in the contents and then once the load has completed call the reveal method. **untested**